# Should I use transacion scope in a shared hosting server?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, transactionscope

Suppose I have to different methods and I place them in the `transaction scope`.
But every method open it's connection. so I need to enable `MSDTC service` in windows server.
but it is a shared hosting server and i can not enable it.

```
class Debit
{
  public void InsertA()
  {
    //InsertCode
  }
}
class Credit
{
   public void InsertB()
  {
   // InsertCode
  }
}
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))

        {
            DebitBAL debit = new DebitBAL();
            CreditBAL credit = new CreditBAL();
            debit.InsertA();
            credit.InsertB();
            ts.complete();
}
```

I use `entity framework` for my statements.
is it a good idea using `transaction scope` in a shared hosting server?

Comment: Related: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/handling-transactions-in-sql-azure.aspx You should consider changing your code so that you don't require distributed transactions, which is not mutually exclusive of using `TransactionScope`.

Answer (score 0):

See  this  link for how to use [transaction scopes with entity framework](http://www.programminginterviews.info/2012/06/entity-framework-transaction-scope.html)

In this link , explained for  three cases in which transaction scope is being used to show rollback when an error occurs during an update of multiple entities:

1: when you have multiple save calls to the context;

2: when you have single save with multiple object;

3: and transactions across multiple contexts.